# retrieve the row number of a JTable from a cell

Tags: java, swing, jtable, selection

I need to know if it is possible to retrieve the row number of a JTable to click on a button located on the inside of the table. I need get the numer of row from a specific cell

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you click on a cell in a table the row will become selected.

To determine the selected row you can use:

```
int row = table.getSelectedRow();
```

Comment: thanks camickr. My problem is that I click on JButton called "Update" and I need that method PerfomedAction tells me which row belongs that button

Comment: @rubystudent, right, so in the ActionLitener you add to the JButton you add the line of code that I just gave you.